# What is the purpose of the <group> tag in jrxml files

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

can anyone explain in very simple words what the `<group>` tag stands for. I already read this: [enter link description here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/groups)

But I can't get it, I played with reports over three hours but can't get any results.

__

I have a csv datasource looking like that:

```
Name | Value
-------------
Ab   | 123
Ba   | wow
Cb   | got
De   | it
```

For instance I would like to get only the entry in the value column where the entry in the Name column is "Cb" (would be "got").
Hence, I created a group with: following expression: `$F{Name}.compareToIgnoreCase("Cb")`

### Unfortunately I always get the entire column although I only want one entry.

Do I use the group tag in the right way? Maybe I have misunderstood the intended purpose of this tag.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

2014-March-22:
I made a simple example [PastBin:minimalcode-jrxml-file](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=ErZ0YhRk) using following csv file as datasource:

```
Name;Tom
Birthday;01-May-1980
Country;Germany
sex;male
```

Here is a screenshot of the design view (ireports 5.5.0):
[image]
And here is what I get when I click on preview (in ireports), unfortunately this is not what i want:
[image]
Maybe anyone can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of this tag is to "*group/unite* data based on a specific column value. Let's take for example the classic HR schema. Every `Employee` is linked with a specific `Department`. While getting all the employees inside a report, you can "*divide"* them in groups based on the department on which they are connected (i.e: by creating a group with for the `employee.department_id` attribute). A simple usage might be creating different tables with employees records for every department. Basically, is the same function as the `Group` clause in SQL (only that Jasper is aware of these groups and allows you to customize them).

In your case, i'm not quite sure that the expression used is creating a jasper-group. Anyway, what you're trying to do (i mean, getting only that record) can be easily accomplished by a "WHERE" clause inside the report query: `WHERE name='Cb'`

Comment: If I could use SQL your consideration would be the easiest way to solve my problem. Unfortunately I use csv files. Therefore I can't use SQL commands :-(

Comment: In that case, try to add the expression: $F{Name}.equalsIgnoreCase("Cb") , inside the <printWhenExpression> tag of the row.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need group use filter expression:

```
<filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}.equalsIgnoreCase("Cb")]]></filterExpression>
```

Comment: Where should I put this expression?

Comment: I always get: **"Error loading the report template:
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 22; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'filterExpression' ....**

Comment: In iReport in Report query window under the list of fields first button is `Filter expression`. In Studio in "Dataset and query" window there is tab named `Filter expression`.

Comment: Isn't it possible to add the xml Tag (expression) you gave me (`<filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}.equalsIgnoreCase("Cb")]]></filterExpression>`) directly to the xml code? I thought everything (every information) is stored in the jrxml file?

Comment: Ok I found one solution: the `<filterExpression>` tag has to be one level below (enclosed with) the `<jasperReport>`tag. Meaning: `<jasperReport> ... <filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}.equalsIgnoreCase("Cb")]]></filterExpression> .... </jasperReport>`. But what to do when I need multiple <filterExpression> in one document. -> see my start post(I attached some information)

Comment: Your source data is not in a proper format for reporting. To be able the layout the way you draw it you should have all the info about a single person in a single row. If you can't change the data, write filter expression to leave only "Name" and "Country" rows. Put "My name is..." and "I'm from..." In the same line and use "Print When" expression to determine which fields to display.